# RubyMine 2018.1.3 - Not able to configure Ruby Interpreter in Mac OS X 10.13.4

Tags: ruby, rubymine

RubyMine shows me an error regarding Ruby Interpreter like below

[image]

Now whenever I click on `Configure Ruby Interpreter` it takes me to the below page and even after selecting the interpreter and pressing `Apply` , the interpreter is not getting configured.

[image]

The same issue with `Configure Cookbooks`. When I try to configure Cookbooks it shows me an window like below and even after doing apply nothing happens.

[image]

Can some one let me know what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project I was working on has both python and ruby files. I have configured PyCharm and then in the same directory I was trying to configure RubyMine for ruby which was causing the issue.

So I checked out the code in a different folder and configured only RubyMine there. Now things are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I have faced the same problem, but for me when I press apply button, it got stuck so I directly pressed the okay button, it has configured the interpreter fine. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally just a case of the message not going away, same thing happens in PyCharm as well. Closing the tab the message is displayed on and re-opening it will make it go away, as well as simply clicking the "play" button to confirm it is indeed working.

Comment: I restarted RubyMine after pressing `OK` button. But still same message.

Comment: Did you test run?